# Send jQuery array on php form submit

Tags: php, jquery

Right now I am updating user_list List using jquery and submitting the form data using Ajax

now I want to submit that form like normal form submit

Here is the problem I am unable to pass the JQuery updated user_list  along form ?

Is There any way to do this ?

What I have tried

```
<script>

var user_names=[];

function check_selected(id){

    user_names.push(id);

        $("#username").val(user_name);

}
</script>
```

Where username is a form field like

```
<input type ="hidden" val = "" id="username" name ="username">
```

Comment: You need to add more detail, at the moment, your question is difficult to understand, perhaps provide more details of what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help or not, but you have used a variable that may have not been initialized

```
$("#username").val(user_name);
```

should be

```
$("#username").val(user_names);    //missing s
```

besides, if you are after sending an array to the server, and the server is php, I would suggest adding [] square brackets at the end of the field name, this is a clean way of sending the list and the server can build the array and you would be able to access it as a list

```
 $_POST['list_name'][index]
```

Answer (score 1):

`val` is not a valid attribute for the `<input />` element. Change it to `value`

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="username" name="username" />
```

Comment: oh i am sorry i forget to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

var user_names=[];

function check_selected(id){

    user_names.push(id);

        $("#username").val(user_names.join(","));

}
</script>
```